# Here in this code why 'ename' should be of char pointer type instead of char array?

Tags: c, argv

I want to initialise structure using command line arguments but I am stuck in between that why we have to take ename be of char pointer type instead of char array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct emp 
    {
      int eno;
      char* ename; 
      int esal;   
    };
int main(int argc,int* argv[])
{
    struct emp e;
    e.eno = (argv[1]);
    e.ename = argv[2];
    e.esal = (argv[3]);
    printf("%d\n",argv[1]); 
    printf("%s\n",argv[2]);
    printf("%d\n",argv[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you cannot assign to arrays, like you are trying in `e.ename = argv[2]`.

Comment: Don't change after I answered. Please.

Comment: Sorry!! @coderredoc

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to get the `int` from the `char*`. Easy solution is to use `atoi` but the good one would be to use `strtol` which provides error checking.

```
e.eno = atoi(argv[1]);
```

For the second one use `strdup` (assuming POSIX compliant `strdup` is there on your system).

```
e.ename = strdup(argv[2]);
```

But yes with the above shown method, add a level error checking and validation of the input code. You have compiled your code with `gcc -Wall -Werror progname.c`
compiler would have shown you the warnings.

To clarify a bit, `e.ename = argv[2]` assigning decayed `char*` to the `ename` member of the structure instance. Array in this case is converted to the pointer to the first element of the char array. Pointer to the first element is nothing but `char*` that's why you required `char*` here. This is not the recommended thing to do because the structure instance then would have side effects beyond it's members. Changing it's member would affect the `argv[2]` and vice versa.

If you took `char` array or declared `ename` as a `char` array then writing this statement would give you error. Because arrays are not modifiable lvalue. Assigning something to them is illegal.

```
struct emp 
{
  int eno;
  char ename[MAXLENGTH]; 
  int esal;   
};
...
strcpy(e.ename,argv[2]);
```

Here before using `strcpy` validate whether `argv[2]` contains something that can be copied into the designated `char` array member.

There are different ways you can use the `ename` member based on how you declared it. `ename` doesn't have to be `char*` - it can be `char` array also but the use must be correct whatever you do.